# Anyone have any experience with the M1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: osx

I’m brand new to Blender so gave it a try on my MacBook Air. I really enjoy it so am thinking of upgrading to the M1 MacBook Pro (16gb Ram).

I know ideally more ram would be great but I travel for work so a laptop is preferred.

We’re also an entirely Apple household so for integration I’m looking at sticking with Apple.

Any first hand insight would be appreciated.

Rich

Comment: M1 16gb here. It's defenitly *not* build for serious 3d work. It's ok for modeling and scripting but that's it. Just too slow for anything else (like lookdev, rendering or simulation).

Comment: Thanks! I want to work up to making 5-10 min kids animated episodes. Do you know much about external graphics cards? Would that be a pain? I’d go a windows pc but we have another MacBook, theee iPads, two iPhones, Apple TV and a home pod. It will just work better with a Mac. I could go desktop but it then restricts me to only working at home. I saw some of the older intel MacBooks pro’s had more ram. Would that be a better option?

Comment: The M1 does not support any egpu (tested). It's a bad choice anyway since you want a nvidia graphics card and at least 32gb of ram, 16gb feels like a bad joke in 2021.

Comment: maybe wait for 16'' ....